# WebApi route with urlEncoded part

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "RestApi",
    routeTemplate: "rest/{storage}/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: new
    {
        id = RouteParameter.Optional,
        action = "Index"
    }
```

{id} parameter can be URI itself, and I encode it. For example, route can be:
**/rest/main/nodes/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.company.com%2Fns%2FGeo%23United_States/rdf**

But this way wrong, it isn't work. With simple {id} parameter it is OK.

What I should do to make it works?

Answer (score 3):

> What I should do to make it works?

Just use query string parameters if you intend to send arbitrary characters to the server:

```
/rest/main/nodes/rdf?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.company.com%2Fns%2FGeo%23United_States
```

You may read the [`following blog post`](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx) from Scott Hanselmann in which he covers the difficulties of using such values in the path portion of the url.

I quote his conclusion:

> After ALL this effort to get crazy stuff in the Request Path, it's
>   worth mentioning that simply keeping the values as a part of the Query
>   String (remember WAY back at the beginning of this post?) is easier,
>   cleaner, more flexible, and more secure.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But it is not right way for REST resources, isn't it?

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with REST. And REST doesn't forbid using query string parameters. REST is about resources and the actions you could perform with those resources.